# How can I configure an Azure WebJob to run from a git deployed exe, rather than from an upload?

Tags: azure, deployment, webjob

I have a deployment process that places everything needed within a repository which my azure AppService is already configured to pull from.
This deployment process is fully automated and works well.

I would like to amend this deployment process to include one or more console applications which would then be configured to be run as WebJobs, either when triggered, or on a continuous basis.

However the configuration for webjobs appears to want me to upload the .exe during configuration, rather than point at a pre-existing .exe.

This seems less than optimal, because it suggests that I'll have to reupload each time said console app changes.

It would be far more convenient to be able to point to a known location within the AppService which contained the full deployment of the WebJob console App.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the deployment process you want couldn't be done. No matter on which way `WebJob` is deployed, Job is copied to the file system on the `Kudu` in essence. And `WebJob` is a function depending on Web App Service, so the deployment couldn't be processed as a whole. You could read the [Wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).

From your description, I suggest you using [`Azure Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview). You also could use `TimeTrigger`、`BlobTrigger`、`HTTPTrigger` etc. You could write just the code you need for the problem at hand, without worrying about a whole application or the infrastructure to run it.

If you still have questions, please let me know.